# How to round image downloaded from web in blackberry cascades using qml

Tags: blackberry, imageview, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a listview that displays a list of userdetails on right and profile pic on left which I get from back end. For downloading and loading the image I'm using a webviewsample image class from github and it works fine. Now I'm need to make the image round. As I searched through web I understand nine slicing is used to do this but I'm not sure how. Each of my listitem has a different background which changes randomly. Below are the sample image of what I have done and what I actually want.

***This is my current list view***

[image]

***This is how I need it to be***

[image]

This is the code of my custom list item that displays this view

```
Container {
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            layout: StackLayout {
                orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
            }

            Container {
                id:profileSubContainer 
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                layout: DockLayout {

                }  


            WebImageView {
                id: profilePic
                url: profilePicture

                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                scalingMethod: ScalingMethod.AspectFit
                visible: (profilePic.loading == 1.0)

            }


            ImageView {
                id: defaultPic
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                scalingMethod: ScalingMethod.AspectFit
                imageSource:  "asset:///Images/defaultProfile.png"
                visible:!profilePic.visible

            }


            layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties 
            {
                spaceQuota: 1
            }
        }



            CustomButtonTextArea {
                id: userName
                layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
                    spaceQuota: 2
                }
                text: username
                textEditable: false
                textAreaStyle: getStyle()

            }



    }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is possible in _Cascades_, but have you try [OpacityMask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html)?

Comment: As I checked I will need to import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0 in my qml but it shows unknown library, do you know what library will I have to include in my pro file so that I can access this?

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? QtGraphicalEffects is only supported in Qt5.4.

Comment: I'm doing this in blackberry cascades using momentics. It uses cpp and qml.

Answer (score 3):

If you have older version of Qt where this isn't supported directly, a rather *hackish* way to do is this :

1. Cut out a circular hole from the background image (Using Photoshop/GIMP etc.) and save it as a PNG.

[image]

2. Now all you need to do is to arrange all the elements in such a way that it *appears* as if the profile pic has been cut out. If you place your profile pic first and then the background image, background image cover the profile pic, leaving only circular part from it visible (Note that it SHOULD be PNG for this to work).

Correct order will be :

```
   a. Profile Image
   b. Background Image
   c. Text
```

You can either write these elements in that order or use the `z` value of elements.

```
Image // Background Image 
{
    z = 2;  
}

Image // Profile Image 
{
    z = 1; 
}

Text  
{
    z = 3; 
}
```

P.S. This is pseudo code, I hope you get the idea. I did something like this with qt 4.8 long back, and it worked liked a charm.

---

**Edit 1.**

In case you want to have background of random color instead of images (as you have asked in the comment), you can try to do this using Qt.

1. Create the custom background with using QPainter or some similar class and some clipping mask to carve out the circular part.
2. Expose this class as a Qml element.
3. Use it for your case by passing random colors while drawing.

They talk of something similar here : http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2066

P.S. Haven't tried it myself, but looks like a good direction if you are stuck otherwise.

Comment: Its a good idea, but as I mentioned earlier my background fills color randomly so a fixed background wouldnt do any good, so if there are 100 colors I will have to create 100 backgrounds like this one. Any other hakish way ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use [OpacityMask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) because your version of Qt doesn't support QtGraphicalEffects, you could do the same trick with [Canvas](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html), that is supported since Qt 5.0.

```
Rectangle{
  id: root
  width: 400
  height: 400

  color: "gray"

  property string imageUrl: "./rabbid.jpg"

  Canvas{
    anchors{
        fill: parent
        margins: 50
    }

    Component.onCompleted:{
        loadImage(imageUrl); // Ready to be used in onPaint handler
    }

    onPaint:{
        console.log("Painting...");
        var context = getContext("2d");
        context.save();

        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.arc(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2, width);
        context.fill();

        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
        context.drawImage(root.imageUrl, 0, 0, width, height);

        context.restore();
    }
  }
}
```

The result:

[image: Round image with canvas]

Since `Context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in"` is set, context operations will be done *inside* previous drawings. Take a look to [Context2D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html) for more info, and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) for a graphical explanation of composite operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately cascades support Qt 4.8 and I can only import QtQuick 1.0 and not 2.0 which has the Canvas class. Is there any other library available that I can include it in cascades?

Comment: Sorry, but I supposed that _Cascades_ support Qt 5.0 at least. I don't know any directly way to do it. May be you can use custom a class inherited from QDeclarativeImageProvider[http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeimageprovider.html] to provide images to QML. When a image is requested you will return an image built with QPainter and the same steps described in my answer.

Comment: The link you gave was broken. Do you have any other link for ref?

Comment: Sorry, it ends with a bracket. [QDeclarativeImageProvider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeimageprovider.html)